# Discrepancy between simulation results and RTL viewer in Quartus II 18.0 for my Verilog code

Tags: verilog, quartus, rtl

Here's the Verilog code for my `UsedBeforeAssign` module:

```vhdl
module UsedBeforeAssign(Din, latch, Dout);
    input latch ;
    input Din;
    output Dout;
    reg Dout;
    reg temp;
    always @(latch or Din or temp)
        if (latch) begin
            Dout = temp;
            temp = Din;
        end
endmodule
```

From a behavioral perspective, I believe that when `latch=1`, `temp` synchronizes with the current `Din`, and `Dout` will be the previous `Din`.

Here's my testbench:

```vhdl
`timescale  1ns / 1ns
module tb_UsedBeforeAssign;

reg         latch     ;
reg         Din       ;
wire        Dout      ;

sram uut (
    .latch     (    latch     ),
    .Din       (    Din       ),
    .Dout      (    Dout      )
);

reg clk;
parameter PERIOD = 10;

initial begin
    $dumpfile("db_tb_sram.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, tb_sram);
    clk = 1'b0;
    forever
        #(PERIOD/2) clk = ~clk;
end

initial begin
   Din = 0;
   latch = 1;
   #PERIOD;
   Din = 1;
   latch = 1;
   #PERIOD;
   Din = 0;
   latch = 1;
   #PERIOD;
   Din = 0;
   latch = 1;
   #PERIOD;
   Din = 1;
   latch = 1;
   #PERIOD;
   Din = 0;
   latch = 1;
   #PERIOD;
    $finish;
end

endmodule
```

I simulated this using Icarus Verilog (iverilog) and the simulation waveform is consistent with my expected behavior.

[image]

However, when I synthesized it using Quartus II 18.0, the RTL viewer showed the following:

[image]

You'll notice that there are two latches in the diagram. When the input `latch` remains at 1, if `Din` changes, due to the latch behavior, the `OUT0` of the `temp` latch will immediately change. Consequently, the input to `dout$latch` changes to match the `OUT0` of the `temp` latch, causing the `OUT0` of `dout$latch` to change immediately. In this case, `Dout` will not always be the previous `Din`, but will instead always match `Din`. This is inconsistent with the simulation results. Why is there a discrepancy between the simulation and the RTL diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using blocking assignment, which means the statements in the always block will be processed in order.

When latch goes high, you have:

```
        Dout = temp;
        temp = Din;
```

First, `Dout = temp;` is executed - this means that the `Dout` signal is expected to take the value that `temp` held when the block was triggered - i.e. the *current* value.

Then you have `temp = Din;`, which will update `temp` to its new value based on the input.

What this implies is that `temp` and `Dout` signals must both be latches (because they are non-clocked but can hold a previous value). Then because `Dout` takes the current value of `temp`, the input of the `Dout` latch must be connected to the output of the `temp` latch. Hence you see a latch chain in the RTL viewer.

In behavioural simulation, the issue appears to be that the always block is not being retriggered. If we try this instead:

```
`timescale  1ns / 1ns

...

always @(latch or Din or temp) begin
    #1;
    $display("%t: Triggered", $time);
    if (latch) begin
        Dout = temp;
        temp = Din;
    end
end
```

With that extra simulation delay, you should now expect to see `Dout` changing value 1ns after `temp` changes if the block retriggered, and the triggered message printed twice.

However this doesn't happen. The changing of `temp` doesn't retrigger the always block due to the way the sensitivity lists work, and therefore you don't see `Dout` updated. This is where simulation and synthesis start to differ, and its the synthesis that is doing the correct thing. Using latches like this is a headache waiting to happen.

Comment: Thank you! I still have 2 questions:
1. I believe the behavioral simulation is incorrect. Why can't the behavioral simulation retrigger? If it can retrigger, it would be in agreement with the synthesis result.
2. I modified `always @(latch or Din or temp)` to `always @(latch or Din)`. This change should not affect the behavioral simulation results, but the synthesis results, particularly the RTL view, should be altered. However, the RTL view of the synthesis results remains unchanged.